# How to authenticate on behalf of user to access their google calendar information from webjob/azure function?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-functions, google-calendar-api, google-api-dotnet-client

We have a webapp that will allow users to sync certain events in their calendar to our system. We can have the user login to google and authorize us to read their calendar and profile.

Now in order to sync their events we want to have an azure function, webjob running at certain intervals that connects to their google calendar and based on some logic will add the event information to our db so that the user can view content in our web app.

How can I get the azure function/webjob to authenticate on the users behalf after they have enabled the featured and authorized out app to get access to their calendar?

=======================================

UPDATE:

This is the code snippet example if anyone else needs it.

```
TokenResponse token = new TokenResponse { RefreshToken = syncUser.GoogleRefreshToken };
UserCredential credentials = new UserCredential(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(
    new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
    {
        ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets
        {
            ClientId = "ClientIDValue",
            ClientSecret = "ClientSecretValue"
        }
    }), "user", token);

CalendarListResource.ListRequest request = service.CalendarList.List();
CalendarList calendars = request.Execute();
```

Comment: well assuming you are storing the users refresh tokens and you can have your azure function read from where ever it is you are storing the fresh token.  You just need to use the refresh token to request a new access token for the user and you can access their data offline.

Comment: @DaImTo You are correct. Could not find that as an obvious answer on their docs. Thank you. 

If you can I would add this to the answer so I can mark it.

Comment: Why arnt you using [Asp .net core](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-asp.net-core-3) you appear to be using the old Asp .net MVC example.

Comment: That is because this is the implementation on the current webjob built on .net. We are working on upgrading to an azure function which will be using the .net core sdk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are storing the users refresh tokens and you can have your azure function read from where ever it is you are storing the refresh token. You just need to use the refresh token to request a new access token for the user and you can access their data offline.

Now I am not an Azure expert, but your going to have to ensure that you set up your redirect uri properly so that azure can get the response back from the authorization.  You should also set your code to handle the refresh token expiring.

Also GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer supports IDataStore which means you could set up your own implementation of Idatastore and use that to feed it the refresh token from where ever it is you are grabbing it from.